# What is industry best practice to combine alphas?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, machine-learning

Say I have 100 different alphas that all have statistically significant returns in-sample.

Is the best practice to use historical covariance matrix plus Markowitz portfolio theory to create an optimal weighting for each alpha?

I have to imagine that there is a way at forecasting covariance that is better than just using historical?

Also I'd imagine there is a better algorithm to weight each alpha?

Answer (score 0):

You add each of those securities to your portfolio until the alpha is zero.

Imagine that I hold the market portfolio and I am considering adding real estate to my portfolio.

I run a regression:
$$r_{realestate} = r_f= \alpha_{realestate} + \beta_{realestate}(r_m - r_f) + \epsilon_{realestate} $$

If the alpha is positive I add the security to my market portfolio. Imagine that I add 50% so that I have 50-50 portfolio. Then I run the regression again:

I run a regression:
$$r_{realestate} = r_f= \alpha_{realestate} + \beta_{realestate}(r_{50,50} - r_f) + \epsilon_{realestate} $$

If the alpha is negative I need to decrease the weight, if it is positive I need to keep adding.

If you run a mean-variance portfolio problem (forget alphas) you will get the **exact** same answer.

Comment: By the exact same answer you mean that the weights will be $\Sigma^{-1} (\mu-r_F)$ normalized to add up to 1 ?

Comment: Yes indeed they will. A regression with the is equivalent to a MV problem.